# Ruby yaml deep merge

Tags: ruby, merge, yaml

I'm fairly new to Ruby and I've inherited some code which does a "deep merge" of some YAML. Here's the relevant part :-

```
class ::Hash
    def deep_merge(second)
        merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : Array === v1 && Array === v2 ? v1 | v2 : [:undefined, nil, :nil].include?(v2) ? v1 : v2 }
        self.merge(second.to_h, &merger)
    end
end
```

which I found fairly unreadable TBH. It falls over when I pass it the following YAML :-

```
- {key: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type, value: basic}
- {key: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret, value: basic-auth}
- {key: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm, value: 'Authentication Required.'}
```

the "-" are all indented in the yaml input, but code formatting is messing with that here.

Here's a stripped down version of the YAML I'm trying to merge with (which also fails)

```
service:
  container:
    port: 3000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are right, it is unreadable. Also there seem to be too many distracting elements here - I suggest cleaning the code first, and providing the most minimal example with a code that we can run, so we can help with the actual problem at hand (for example, seems like we don't need to talk about YAML here, since the method in question deals with hashes).

Comment: Agreed about simplifying. Once I did that it became clear what the problem was, and it was in the YAML. (see answer). I'm not sure if this will be helpful to anyone else, so not sure if I should just delete the whole question (or even if I can do that!?)

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem. I had forgotten to add a label to the YAML (annotations:) and as soon as I put that on, it started working again. Should I delete the question?